# API and app for sending notifications to iPhone?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

In a project I'm working on, I want to send notifications to my user's iPhone from my Chrome extension. The notifications will mostly be about their accounts on my site, and I would like them to be able to reply with the type of action they want taken concerning the alerts.

To help me do this, I found <s>http://pushme.to/</s><sub>1</sub> which works by allowing the iPhone owner to download their app, create an account via that app, and from then on be able to receive
"IM"-like messages and push notifications. I can send my iPhone users messages via http://pushme.to/iphone_users_username by automating that page with JavaScript. However, it will be imperative that I also send images along with the alerts, and am unable to do that as the site uses a flash uploader.

[**EDIT:** To clarify - pushme.to has a feature that allows you to send along images with a message, this is what I was referring to]

So, to cut to the chase and hit the bottom line: does anyone know of an app the provides a companion app & API for sending messages that the user can reply to? Meaning that the user receives my messages, can reply to them - and my Chrome Extension receive their replies?

---

<sub>1</sub> Service no longer active

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> However, it will be imperative that I also send images along with the alerts

I might be misunderstanding your question, but the push notification framework doesn't support images. You can only send text, badges (the red numbers next to an app icon), or sounds (which must already be installed in the app bundle).

Perhaps you can use a third-party option to do it, but push.me wasn't really designed for automated comms, but for friend to friend IMs. You may have to create your own app to achieve this...I'm not sure of any third party app you could use.

Comment: In addition to that: You could hyperlink your images with URLs and minify them beforehand so you dont burst the payload of a push notification.

Comment: Whoops, what I mean to say - pushme.to (the online version) has a feature where you can upload and send images along with the messages. This is what I was referring to.